# ask the user for a non negative integer using the while loop

Tags: python

Write a program that does the following: ask the user for a nonnegative integer, using the while loop, calculate and print out the factorial of the input (you are not allowed to use the math module or the math.factorial() function). The user may provide 0, output should be 0! = 1. If the user enters a negative integer then write a message for the user that an nonnegative integer is  expected and end the program.

Comment: Please try to solve the problem on your own. You can than ask questions if your implementation does not do what you want.

Comment: Based on your question and comments on the answers, it is obvious that you are seeking a full solution to your problem. Please be aware that Stack Overflow is not a free coding service and such questions will be quickly closed. You are expected to make an attempt to solve your problem, research your difficulties and, if you cannot find an answer, post a **specific** question here. Please repeat the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just for fun (if the input is `n`): `import functools, operator` followed by `print('non-negative integer is expected' if int(n)<0 else functools.reduce(operator.__mul__, range(1, int(n)+1), 1))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
num = -1
while num < 0:
    num=int(input())
factorial=1
for i in range(1, num+1):
    factorial *= i
print(factorial)
```

P.S. Looks like programming homework :) Please, solve it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

We first define a variable with value 1 then multiply it with from 1 to n 
then return the answer

```
def fact(n):
    if n<0:
        return "an nonnegative integer is expected"
    result = 1
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        result *= i
    return f"{n} != {result}"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(fact(int(input())))
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying but this is the full solution to it?

Comment: This is the full solution to it please explain me what you don't understand

Comment: #include<stodio.h}
int main(void)
int n,f=1;
Print ("enter no. for calculating factorial:");
scanf("%d",&n);
if (n!=0)
{
int c=n;// creating a copy of the number.
while(c>0)
f=f*c;//storing the factorial
c=c-1;
}
{
print ('factorial of %dis%d',n,f);
return 0;
}

Comment: this is what i had so far, and what i dont understand ( and you dont have to explain ) everything, programming isnt my thing im just trying to finish practice homework and then have a sit down with my doctor so he can explain it for me

Comment: I am and i have written this program ^^ but it doesn't seem right to me and it's too complicated of an answer?